# Qt with visual studio , Qt requires a c++17 compiler

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I'm stuck on this, when i compile a project in Visual Studio i have this error at the ouput,  telling that:

```
on nmvc you must the /Zc:__cplusplus option to the compiler (compiling source file QtdesignerWidget.cpp)
```

I tried the solution to add /Zc:__cplusplus in the project properties -C++ / Command line / Additional options withou success
And when i try to make a .pro file in QT VS tools it makes this error:

```
Warning : Cannot Find any Qt4 projects to export
```

Comment: I think you need to describe what you are doing. I use Qt with Visual Studio at work without issue. (many versions over the last 13 years).

Comment: ***Cannot Find any Qt4 projects to export*** Are you using Qt4? I don't think that works with any version of Visual Studio greater than 2013 (without a bit of patching of Qt and fixes). Related: [https://forum.qt.io/topic/91623/building-qt-4-8-7-with-visual-studio-2017/10](https://forum.qt.io/topic/91623/building-qt-4-8-7-with-visual-studio-2017/10)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Set C++ compiler and build properties in Visual Studio.
2. Select the Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line property page.
3. Add /Zc:__cplusplus or /Zc:__cplusplus- to the Additional options: pane.

The answer is taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Here are my platforms:
Qt version: 6.2.0
Qt Visual Studio Tools version: 3.4
Compiler version: VS2019_64

Luckily, I also installed Qt5.14.2 on my computer. When I changed configurations to: Qt5.14.2 and VS2017_64. Problem solved. So I guess VS2019 or Qt VS tools3.4 doesn't work well with Qt6.2.0.

You can have a try.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is a repository of great answers (to great question). Please, don't post "guesses" or proposed answers that you can't verify.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your language standard is set to C++17 in the project settings?

Go to project properties --> General --> C++ Language Standard

In my case it was default set to C++14. This must be set to C++17.